# Is there a simple way to manage local state with Apollo Client 2.5 for React? What is the 'read' equivalent to 'client.writeData'?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'me learning the local state management capabilities of Apollo Client 2.5 and finding it rather confusing. For what it's worth, I was able to understand Apollo Server pretty readily, but this is proving more daunting.

I (kind of) understand how to use it when one wants to set up local resolvers and queries to read local state, but is there a way to simply set some local state variables, as one can pretty easily with Redux.  For example, setting `isLoggedIn` as `true` on the completion of a login mutation? I tried this (following https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state)

```
return <Mutation mutation={LOGIN} onCompleted={data => {
      if (data && data.login) {
        const {login: {token}} = data
        if (token) {
          history.push('/list')
        }
      }
    }}>
      {(register, {data, error, loading, client}) => {

        if (error) {
          return <div>{error.toString()}</div>
        }
        if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
        if (data && data.login) {
          const {login: {token}} = data
          if (token) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', token)
            client.writeData({isLoggedIn:true})
          }
```

but got the error

> Error: Error writing result to store for query: 
>   {"kind":"Document","definitions":[{"kind":"OperationDefinition","operation":"query","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"GeneratedClientQuery"},"selectionSet":null}]}
>   Cannot read property 'selections' of null

But I don't know if I'm using `writeData` correctly.  More importantly, how to I *read* the data?  There doesn't seem to be a corresponding `readData` call in the API.  Do I need to set up a GraphQL query and run that to see if the user is logged in?  Do I need to then make a resolver for that query and include it when constructing the Apollo Client?

I saw some examples using `apollo-link-state` that seemed to be simpler, but apparently that's deprecated and included in Apollo Client 2.5.

Clearly I am not seeing the forest for the trees, and would welcome any advice.

Answer (score 4):

You almost have it , you just forgot to pass the data in the data object instead of directly ==>

client.writeData({ data: { isLoggedIn: false } });